# iTunes Store Operation Failed error: 122 (51) while uploading .ipa to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm receiving this error when uploading my archive file. I have tried a lot of things and don't know what's going on.

Also there are not similar issues in the web.

Errors are:

```
Destination: Disk quota exceeded (5)
iTunes Store Operation Failed error: 122 (51)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please try once from Application Loader...It may help..

Comment: I tried Validate instead of direct Upload. And this gave me the real reason why the .IPA was not valid. Thanks!

Comment: Apple had announced a downtime for iTunes for this week. You probably tried it in that time.

Comment: Downtime was yesterday 6-8 am P.T. (I hit my upload try in the moment).  I have the same issue today with uploading .ipa by Application Loader

Comment: The error is resolved, I guess that was from iTunes side. I was also facing this issue and then i tried using application loader and after 15-20mins it uploaded successfully.

Comment: not resolved for now

Comment: they just have rebooted itunes server (at least they wrote so), and upload succeed

Comment: it just worked for me using the same build that didn't work an hour ago so I'd say it was a problem with apple's servers

Comment: is not working yet. is this just with me? Apple will owe me some hours of my life.

Comment: Did you already try to Validate ? Instead of Upload?

Comment: Also try to put a higher version. This and validate worked for me.

Comment: I was getting these disk quota messages too... until I bumped the version number.  Not sure if it's something to do with the old failed version still hanging around on iTunesConnect showing "Processing" (when before that scheduled downtime so far as I'd remember failed uploads would just disappear).

Comment: Out of interest, has anyone having this issue enabled the `-Osize` Swift optimisation level on release builds?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should [validate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xX2K.png) your *.ipa and fix the real problem. 
In my case it was

> Invalid App Store Icon. The App Store Icon in the asset catalog in
>   '***.app' can't be transparent nor contain an alpha channel.

[image: validate]

Answer (score 3):

I just noticed this too, after performing a validate it turns out I had **forgotten to increase the version**, wonderfully stupid.

The less said about the "iTunes Store Operation Failed" error of "Destination: Disk quota exceeded" the better.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the question of apple...
Now it works, I did not change anything, so this is Apple's problem

Comment: This was the case for me. Disk Quota error, knowing how flaky their servers have been of late, I try again wit the identical IPA, goes through fine, no error.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. In my case the version is not the problem because is the first upload of my app. It seems there are problems in Apple servers

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. All I did to fix this was:

1.Added all sizes App Icons, including 1024*1024

2.Disable Bitcode while archiving (see screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fought with the same issue the whole morning today...

In my case the error list contained one another error (something related to wrong signing profiles). After I fixed the issue with wrong profiles, the problem with "Disk quota exceeded / error: 122" didn't occur anymore.

The question is: Have you got any other issues on your error list? Maybe solving them will fix your problem as well as in mine case.

Maybe you have got another issue doesn't listed on the error list? Try 'Validate' your app first before sending to AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

Use officially released, **not Beta version of Xcode** for builds archiving.