# Destination: Disk quota exceeded

Tags: app-store

When publishing an app using Application Publisher, after nearly ten minutes, I get the following error...

> The status is FAILED for the file named
>   /var/folders/yt/v3w7j1ws45d7s_7328dyn_6c0000gn/T/e6e327f5-e6b6-4645-876e-042274753a135949007606868121680dir/64fb63f5-da16-43cd-9b01-4f4ce22e23536929388045350435111.txt
>   and the error description is 'Destination: Disk quota exceeded (5)'

Any ideas?

Comment: it will pop up an error message if user try to go over in the form of a read/write error. Check your quota.

Comment: It's a brand new account!

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49043398/1402846

Answer (score 1):

Looks like apple might be having some server issues, though their status page says otherwise, I too am getting this issue

https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Comment: What a relief. Although I have another couple of errors too. :)

Comment: Worked first time today.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error. My problem was that I was trying to upload an archive with the same version number as already reviewed and published on the app store. The solution here was to:

- login into app connect, select the app
- create new version app version: "(+) version or platform"-button in the left menu
- set new version number
- distribute new archive with exact same version number as set in app connect

Upload is now successul